# Datatables exibe erro ao tentar carregar arquivo json

Tags: php, javascript, html

Alguém pode me ajudar? Já pesquisei vários temas aqui no SO mas ainda não consegui resolver meu problema.

Fiz uma consulta ao banco de dados via ajax para verificar os horários disponíveis de algumas salas de aula. Gerei um arquivo JSON do resultado dessa query e, através do DataTables, exibo os dados.

Até aí tudo bem. Quando tento fazer uma segunda consulta, o DataTables exibe um erro dizendo que a table já foi inicializada.

Abaixo está o meu código:

```
$("#formViewDisponib").validate({
    unkeyup: false,
    // Define as regras
    submitHandler: function( form ){
        var dados = $( form ).serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $( form ).attr('action'), // "qryDisponib.php",  
            data: dados,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function( data ){ // Executa a função se a requisição funcionar
                var msgFinal = data.msgFinal;
                var table = $('#tbDisponib').DataTable({
                   language:{
                        "sEmptyTable": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                        "sInfo": "Mostrando de _START_ até _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros",
                        "sInfoEmpty": "Mostrando 0 até 0 de 0 registros",
                        "sInfoFiltered": "(Filtrados de _MAX_ registros)",
                        "sInfoPostFix": "",
                        "sInfoThousands": ".",
                        "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ resultados por página",
                        "sLoadingRecords": "Carregando...",
                        "sProcessing": "Processando...",
                        "sZeroRecords": "Nenhum registro encontrado",
                        "sSearch": "Pesquisar",
                        "oPaginate": {
                            "sNext": "Próximo",
                            "sPrevious": "Anterior",
                            "sFirst": "Primeiro",
                            "sLast": "Último"
                        },
                        "oAria": {
                            "sSortAscending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma ascendente",
                            "sSortDescending": ": Ordenar colunas de forma descendente"
                        }
                    },
                    scrollY: "200px",
                    scrollX: true,
                    scrollCollapse: true,
                    searching: false,
                    ordering: false,
                    paging: false,
                    fixedColumns:   {
                        leftColumns: 2
                    },
                    "ajax" : "tabela.json"
                });
                //$('#resultViewDisponib').html(msgFinal);
                $('#resultViewDisponib').show('slow');
            },
            beforeSend: function(){ // Executa a função assim que a requisição for enviada
                $('#loadViewDisponib').css({display:"block"});
            },
            complete: function(){ // Executa a função sempre que a requisição for executada
                $('#loadViewDisponib').css({display:"none"});
            },
            error: function(){
                bootbox.alert("Falha de Conexão!<br />Não foi possível efetuar sua requisição.<br/>Aguarde alguns instantes e faça uma nova tentativa.");
            }
        });
        return false;
    }
});
```

O HTML:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="cxViewDisponib" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title text-left" id="myModalLabel">Disponibilidade de horários</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form class="form-inline" role="formViewDisponib" id="formViewDisponib" name="formViewDisponib" method="POST" action="qryDisponib.php">
                    <fieldset>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="mesRef" class="control-label">Mês</label><br /> 
                        <select name="mesRef" class="form-control selectpicker show-menu-arrow show-tick" data-width="auto">
                            <optgroup label="Selecione o mês desejado">
                            <?php
                                for($i=0; $i<sizeof($nomemeses); $i++){
                                    echo "<option value='".str_pad(($i+1),2,'0',STR_PAD_LEFT)."'";
                                    if(($i+1)==$mesRef){
                                        echo " SELECTED";
                                    }
                                    echo ">".$nomemeses[$i]."</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="anoRef" class="control-label">Ano</label><br /> 
                        <select name="anoRef" class="form-control selectpicker show-menu-arrow show-tick" data-width="auto">
                            <optgroup label="Selecione o ano desejado">
                            <?php
                                for($listano=(date('Y')-3);($listano >= (date('Y')-3) && $listano <= (date('Y')+10));$listano++){
                                    echo "<option value='".$listano."'";
                                    if($listano==$anoRef){
                                        echo " SELECTED";
                                    }
                                    echo ">" . $listano . "</option>";
                                }
                            ?>
                            </optgroup>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-actions">
                        <button type="submit" name="enviar" value="enviar" class="btn btn-primary btn-large pull-left">Pesquisar</button>
                    </div>
                    </fieldset>
                </form>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <div id="loadViewDisponib"><img src="Imagens/ajax-loader.gif" /></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <table class='display' id='tbDisponib'>
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th rowspan='3' class='text-center t_hCol'>Dia</th>
                                    <th rowspan='3' class='text-center t_hCol'>Semana</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <?php

                                    $vez = 0;
                                    foreach( $_SESSION["horario_operacao"] as $interv_horario ){
                                        if( ( $vez++ % 2 ) > 0 ){
                                            echo "<th class='text-center info' colspan='" . count( $_SESSION['tabEspacos'] ) . "'>" . $interv_horario . "</th>";
                                        }else{
                                            echo "<th class='text-center warning' colspan='" . count( $_SESSION['tabEspacos'] ) . "'>" . $interv_horario . "</th>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                                    for( $y=0; $y<=count( $_SESSION["horario_operacao"] )-1; $y++ ){
                                        foreach( $_SESSION['tabEspacos'] as $chave => $valor ){
                                            echo "<th class='text-center t_hCol'>" . trim( $_SESSION['tabEspacos'][$chave]['NOME'] ) . "</th>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    echo "</tr>";

                                ?>
                            </thead>
                            <tfoot>
                                <tr>
                                    <th rowspan='3' class='text-center t_hCol'>Dia</th>
                                    <th rowspan='3' class='text-center t_hCol'>Semana</th>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                <?php

                                    for( $y=0; $y<=count( $_SESSION["horario_operacao"] )-1; $y++ ){
                                        foreach( $_SESSION['tabEspacos'] as $chave => $valor ){
                                            echo "<th class='text-center t_hCol'>" . trim( $_SESSION['tabEspacos'][$chave]['NOME'] ) . "</th>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    echo "</tr><tr>";
                                    $vez = 0;
                                    foreach( $_SESSION["horario_operacao"] as $interv_horario ){
                                        if( ( $vez++ % 2 ) > 0 ){
                                            echo "<th class='text-center info' colspan='" . count( $_SESSION['tabEspacos'] ) . "'>" . $interv_horario . "</th>";
                                        }else{
                                            echo "<th class='text-center warning' colspan='" . count( $_SESSION['tabEspacos'] ) . "'>" . $interv_horario . "</th>";
                                        }
                                    }
                                    echo "</tr>";

                                ?>
                            </tfoot>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Fechar</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

e o PHP:

```
    if( !isset( $_SESSION["userlogado"] ) || !( $_SESSION["userlogado"]=="SIM" ) ){
        print "<script>location.href='logout.php';</script>";
        exit;
    }
    include "conexao.php";
    //include "autentic.php";

    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){

        // recuperar os dados do form
        $mesPesq = getPost('mesRef');
        $anoPesq = getPost('anoRef');

        if( !( $mesPesq==null ) && !( $anoPesq==null ) ){
            $mesano = $mesPesq . "/" . $anoPesq;
            $stCancel = "N";

            // Recuperar as reservas de todos os locais do mês/ano solicitado
            $vetReservasAtivas = array();
            $strsql  = "SELECT ID,IDESPACO,IDAREA,CALEND,DATAHORAI,DATAHORAF,";
            $strsql .= "TOTMINUTOS,STATUS,REFERENCIA FROM reservas ";
            $strsql .= "WHERE ( REFERENCIA=:mesano AND STATUS=:stCancel ) ORDER BY CALEND,IDESPACO,DATAHORAI";
            $stmt_reservas_ativas = $cnxBanco->prepare( $strsql );
            $stmt_reservas_ativas->bindParam( ':mesano',$mesano );
            $stmt_reservas_ativas->bindParam( ':stCancel',$stCancel );
            $stmt_reservas_ativas->execute();
            if( $stmt_reservas_ativas->rowCount()>0 ){
                // popular o array com a consulta
                while( $regReservasAtivas = $stmt_reservas_ativas->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ){
                    $vetReservasAtivas[] = $regReservasAtivas;
                }

                // popular o array e gravar o arquivo JSON 
                // com a querie solicitada
                $dth_corrente = new DateTime( $anoPesq . '-' . $mesPesq . '-' . '01' );
                $dth_final = new DateTime( $anoPesq . '-' . $mesPesq . '-' . $dth_corrente->format('t') );
                $numero_salas = count( $_SESSION['tabEspacos'] );
                $sala_atual = 1;
                $contador = 0;
                $dados = $linha = array();


                // preparar o corpo da table
                while( $dth_corrente<=$dth_final ){
                    // extrair do array de reservas a data pesquisada
                    // verificar cada horário de operação das salas
                    $linha[] = $dth_corrente->format('d/m');
                    $linha[] = $dth_corrente->format('D');
                    foreach( $_SESSION["horario_operacao"] as $hourOperacao ){
                        $dth_avaliadai = $dth_corrente->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . substr( $hourOperacao,0,5 ) . ':00';
                        $dth_avaliadaf = $dth_corrente->format('Y-m-d') . ' ' . substr( $hourOperacao,6,5 ) . ':00';

                        foreach( $_SESSION['tabEspacos'] as $chave1 => $valor1 ){
                            $statDisp = "vago";
                            $local_corrente = $_SESSION['tabEspacos'][$chave1]['ID'];

                            foreach( $vetReservasAtivas as $chave2 => $valor2 ){

                                if( $vetReservasAtivas[$chave2]['CALEND']==$dth_corrente->format('Y-m-d') && $vetReservasAtivas[$chave2]['IDESPACO']==$local_corrente ){

                                    if( !faixaSobrepoeIntervaloAberto( $dth_avaliadai,$dth_avaliadaf,$vetReservasAtivas[$chave2]['DATAHORAI'],$vetReservasAtivas[$chave2]['DATAHORAF'] ) &&
                                    !faixaSobrepoeIntervaloFechado( $dth_avaliadai,$dth_avaliadaf,$vetReservasAtivas[$chave2]['DATAHORAI'],$vetReservasAtivas[$chave2]['DATAHORAF'] ) ){
                                        $statDisp = "ocupado";
                                        break;
                                    }

                                }

                            }
                            $linha[] = ( $statDisp=="ocupado" ) ? " X " : " ";
                        }
                    }
                    $dados[] = $linha;
                    $linha = array(); // reiniciar o array;
                    $dth_corrente->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));
                }
                //echo "<pre>";
                //echo print_r( $dados );
                //echo "</pre>";

                $msgFinal = "";
                // gerar o arquivo json
                // Adiciona o identificador "Contatos" aos dados
                $dados_identificador = array('data' => $dados);

                // Tranforma o array $dados_identificador em JSON
                $dados_json = json_encode($dados_identificador);

                if( file_exists( "tabela.json" ))
                    unlink( "tabela.json" );

                // Abre ou cria o arquivo contato.json
                // "a" indicar que o arquivo é aberto para ser escrito
                $fp = fopen("tabela.json", "a");

                // Escreve o conteúdo JSON no arquivo
                $escreve = fwrite($fp, $dados_json);

                // Fecha o arquivo
                fclose($fp);

            }else{
                $msgFinal = "<b>Você deve informar os dados solicitados para a pesquisa.</b>";
            }
        }else{
            $msgFinal = "<b>Você deve informar os dados solicitados para a pesquisa.</b>";
        }
        $vetFinal = array( "msgFinal" => $msgFinal );
        echo json_encode( $vetFinal );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Já tive esse problema e não to muito lembrado qual a opção é a certa porque já faz um tempo mais acho que é a propriedade serverSide ou destroy. Tenta algumas dessas opções abaixo:

```
"processing": true,
"serverSide": true,
"pageLength": 5,
"searching":false,
"destroy": true,
```

Comment: Ederson somente o parâmetro destroy resolveu a questão. Obrigado!

Comment: de nada amigo, que bom que ajudou.